# How to iterate in reverse in a matrix from a specific point?

Tags: python, matrix

If I have a 3x5 matrix, and I want to iterate backwards from cell (i,j) to the beginning of the matrix what would be the best way of doing that? Example:

```
matrix = [[1,0,2,0,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0]]
```

Example: from (1,1) to (0,0) in the matrix we would print out: `0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1`

I tried the following code but this doesn't work as it ends up "slicing" the matrix.

```
for row in reversed(range(i+1)):
    for col in reversed(range(j+1)):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def itrate_mat(i,j, matrix):
    my_list = matrix[i][:j+1][::-1]
    while i > 0:
        my_list.extend(matrix[i-1][::-1])
        i -= 1
    return my_list
itrate_mat(1,1,matrix)
>>[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
```

By using following function you can get a list and iterate using following list. Alternatively, you can make modifications in the loop inside function to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try just iterating over the matrix how you normally would and creating if statements to section off parts that you don't need. While iterating append the values into a new list and then just simply reverse that list. This code I wrote below works:

```
matrix = [[1,0,2,0,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0]]
          
result = [] # the list where u will store result

row = len(matrix) # number of rows
col = len(matrix[0]) # number of columns

# index (1,1) is where you would like to reverse from
last_row = 1 
last_col = 1

# iterate over matrix normally and append till where you need to stop
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        if i < last_row:
            result.append(matrix[i][j])
        elif (i == last_row and j <= last_col):
            result.append(matrix[i][j])
            
#reversing the list you created
result.reverse()
```